# Identifying thread unsafe data structures used by different threads simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

There is a legacy project that contains hundreds of thousands SLOC and runs a lot of different threads.

There is a data structure that contains non-atomic member, that theoretically may be used by different threads, but due to high complexity of code it may be difficult to identify this case from a simple code analysis.

Timings not always cause the crash but it may happen (e.g. this member uses heap).

Is there any way to identify such variables or e.g. during the testing make application crash during the first access of this variable by thread that is different from the thread that accessed it before?

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html

Comment: Is this variable being accessed via a getter or through the object directly?

Comment: @NathanOliver The variable is a private member that is overwritten in a public method

Comment: @DavideSpataro this is a good idea, I didn't know about such tool. On the other hand I as a developer want to be able to mark variable as unsafe and make other developer that uses this structure think about thread safety.

Comment: [Thread sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) (available for Clang & GCC) is *excellent* for spotting problems like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `clang++` with [**ThreadSanitizer**](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html). This involves recompiling your code with `-fsanitize=thread -ltsan`, and executing it. TSan should detect data races and give you stack traces to figure out what's causing them.

> ThreadSanitizer is a tool that detects data races. It consists of a compiler instrumentation module and a run-time library. Typical slowdown introduced by ThreadSanitizer is about 5x-15x. Typical memory overhead introduced by ThreadSanitizer is about 5x-10x.